Access new refresh_token for OAuth2 (nodemailer with Gmail API)
I'm using Next.js with typesript and 'googleapis' library for one of my apps and I need to handle Nodemailer with Gmail API. It requires OAuth2 to work.
When I setup the 0Auth2 from google cloud console and obtain the refresh token I store it in .env local file (its just for testing, later i will store it in a database) and everything seems to work fine and I can send mails through the app. The problem occurs when the refresh token expires and I need to get the new one through my app as I get this error now :
config: {
    retry: true,
    retryConfig: {
      httpMethodsToRetry: [Array],
      currentRetryAttempt: 0,
      retry: 3,
      noResponseRetries: 2,
      retryDelayMultiplier: 2,
      timeOfFirstRequest: 1722252617571,
      totalTimeout: 9007199254740991,
      maxRetryDelay: 9007199254740991,
      statusCodesToRetry: [Array]
    },
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
    data: '<<REDACTED> - See `errorRedactor` option in `gaxios` for configuration>.',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/9.11.0',
      'x-goog-api-client': 'gl-node/20.9.0'
    },
    paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],
    body: '<<REDACTED> - See `errorRedactor` option in `gaxios` for configuration>.',
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    responseType: 'unknown',
    errorRedactor: [Function: defaultErrorRedactor]
  },
  response: {
    config: {
      retry: true,
      retryConfig: [Object],
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
      data: '<<REDACTED> - See `errorRedactor` option in `gaxios` for configuration>.',
      headers: [Object],
      paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],
      body: '<<REDACTED> - See `errorRedactor` option in `gaxios` for configuration>.',
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      responseType: 'unknown',
      errorRedactor: [Function: defaultErrorRedactor]
    },
    data: {
      error: 'invalid_grant',
      error_description: 'Token has been expired or revoked.'
    },
    headers: {
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      date: 'Mon, 29 Jul 2024 11:30:17 GMT',
      expires: 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
      pragma: 'no-cache',
      server: 'scaffolding on HTTPServer2',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-xss-protection': '0'
    },
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    request: { responseURL: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' }
  },
  error: undefined,
  status: 400,
  [Symbol(gaxios-gaxios-error)]: '6.7.0'
}
 POST /api/contact 500 in 1132ms

My code:


import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import {google} from 'googleapis';
import cors from 'cors';
import { createRouter} from 'next-connect';

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: ['POST'],
  };

const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
dotenv.config();

const jwtSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
const gmailAcc = process.env.EMAIL_USER;
const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
const redirectUri = process.env.REDIRECT_URI;
const refreshToken = process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN;
const captchaSecret = process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET;

if (!jwtSecret || !gmailAcc) {
    throw new Error('Environment variables ADMIN_USERNAME, ADMIN_PASSWORD, and JWT_SECRET must be set');
  };

  const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    clientId,
    clientSecret,
    redirectUri
  );

  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: refreshToken
  });

  async function getAccessToken() {
    const { token } = await oauth2Client.getAccessToken();
    return token;
  }
  

async function createTransporter() {
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
    //console.log(accessToken)
    return nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: gmailAcc,
        clientId: clientId,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        refreshToken: refreshToken,
        accessToken: accessToken,
      },
    } as nodemailer.TransportOptions);
  };

const sendMailRouter = createRouter<NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse>();

sendMailRouter.use(cors(corsOptions));

sendMailRouter.post(async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse)=> {
    const {userName, email, message, captcha} = req.body;
    const verifyUrl = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${captchaSecret}&response=${captcha}`;
    const recaptchaResponse = await fetch(verifyUrl, { method: 'POST' });
    const recaptchaResult = await recaptchaResponse.json();

    if(
        !userName 
        || 
        !email 
        || 
        !message
       )
    {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'All input fields are required!' });
    }
    if (
        !recaptchaResponse.ok 
        || 
        !recaptchaResult.success 
        || 
        recaptchaResult.score <= 0.4        
    ){
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Anti-spam protection!' });
    }
    const mailOptions = {
        to: gmailAcc,
        from: email,
        subject: `Съобщение от ${userName}, изпратено от www.yavorm.com`,
        text: `${message}`,
      };
    
    try {
        const transporter = await createTransporter();
        await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Message sent! Thank You!' });
    } catch (error:any) {
        console.error('Error sending email:', error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error sending email!' });
    }
})

export default sendMailRouter.handler({
    onError: (err:any, req, res) => {
      console.error(err.stack);
    },
  });



Can you please show me how can I obtain the new token? What I am doing wrong here?

refresh token are long lived and designed not to expire except under specific circumstances
oauth2#expiration
You must write your code to anticipate the possibility that a granted refresh token might no longer work. A refresh token might stop working for one of these reasons:
The user has revoked your app's access.

The refresh token has not been used for six months.
The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.
If an admin set any of the services requested in your app's scopes to Restricted (the error is admin_policy_enforced).
For Google Cloud Platform APIs - the session length set by the admin could have been exceeded.

A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days, unless the only OAuth scopes requested are a subset of name, email address, and user profile (through the userinfo.email, userinfo.profile, openid scopes, or their OpenID Connect equivalents).
If your app is still in testing your refresh token will expire after seven days.  To fix that set it into production then it will not expire.
My Node.js web Gmail sample
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.

const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'C:\\Development\\FreeLance\\GoogleSamples\\Credentials\\CredWebEverything.json';

/**
 * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
 *
 * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
 */
async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
        const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
        const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
        return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file comptible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
    const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'authorized_user',
        client_id: key.client_id,
        client_secret: key.client_secret,
        refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
        return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
        scopes: SCOPES,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
        await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    return client;
}

/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
async function listLabels(auth) {
    const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
    const res = await gmail.users.labels.list({
        userId: 'me',
    });
    const labels = res.data.labels;
    if (!labels || labels.length === 0) {
        console.log('No labels found.');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Labels:');
    labels.forEach((label) => {
        console.log(`- ${label.name}`);
    });
}

authorize().then(listLabels).catch(console.error);

Sorry i haven't updated my nodemailer sample to use Xoauth2 yet. It should just be a matter of taking the authorization code above and applying it to your nodemailer code.

Hey, Thank you for your answer. Yes, the app is in test mode in google cloud console. But when I obtain a new refresh token from OAuth2 playground it is saying that it will expire in 3600 seconds not 7 days. It's very frustrating that i can't find any newer information about that. However even if I set it to 'Production' status indeed there is a possibility the refresh token to expire again and I can't find how to handle that in my code in any documentation.

EDIT: 3600 second is for the ACCESS token. You are right. Still - I can't find how to handle refresh token expiration

dont use OAuth2 playground unless you are using your own client id and client secret to  generate the tokens.      If you use that every time it expires your going to have to do it though that again.  Your code should be requesting authorization of the user oauth playground is just for development testing not for a production ready application.

The user will send mails through a form on the app to my own gmail acc. Why should it request authorization of the user at all? Am I wrong? Indeed I want to use only my client id and client secret for generation of the tokens.

You need to authorize your code once so that you have a refresh token that accesses your account.  Then your user can send emails though your account.   Really it would be better if you had a google workspace account and used a service account rather then Oauth2
